# multicast packages are there but can not be accessed

Tags: networking, kernel, multicast, sysctl

my box runs ubuntu 14.04. it is an old 32bit box with 4 ether nics.
what i want to achieve is multicast routing from an upstream interface (eth2.8 - dynamic ip) to a downstream interfcae (eth0.13 - 192.168.40.1).
my laptop attached to above box via eth0.13 can read multicast from 40.1 like a charm.
i verified that by running vlc as a server on 40.1

```
cvlc -vvv ./POS-Movie-927x521.mov --sout udp:239.255.12.42 --ttl 12
```

and receiving the stream on my laptop with

```
vlc udp://@239.255.12.42
```

that works even the other way round, sending with my laptop and receiving on the serverside.

so why is it not possible to access multicast packages via eth2.8?

joining works. i can verify arriving packages by

```
sudo tcpdump -i eth2.8 -n multicast
```

but it seems simply impossible to access these packages without tcpdump!
[this exactly describes what i am experiencing](https://serverfault.com/questions/163244/linux-kernel-not-passing-through-multicast-udp-packets), alone the solution is not the same.

here some sysctl parameter:

- net.ipv4.conf.eth2/8.rp_filter = 1
- net.ipv4.conf.eth2/8.mc_forwarding
  = 1
- net.ipv4.conf.eth2/8.forwarding = 1

there is no difference between sysctl params of eth2.8 and eth0.13.

and yes, this happens even if the firewall is down!

any hint appreciated, you'll make my week!

/markus

Answer (score 0):

the unicast route to the upstream hosts where missing!
the interface did accept incoming igmp traffic from an ip in its own class c net but refused packets from other hosts.
unluckily the upstream is from some completely diffent network.
a simple "ip route add ip/mask dev eth2.8" finally solved all problems.